# Body message does not appear when sending attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

When I send attachments, I don't see the body message (message.setText(this.getEmailBody());) in the email.
Without attachments, the email appears with the body message. Emails are sent to a gmail account. Any clue why is this happening?

```
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session_m);    
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.getEmailSender()));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(this.getEmailRecipient()));
        message.setSubject(this.getEmailSubject());
        message.setText(this.getEmailBody()); //This won't be displayed if set attachments

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        for(String file: getAttachmentNameList()){
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.attachFile(this.attachmentsDir.concat(file.trim()));
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);
        }


        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Email has been sent");
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the following:

```
         // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        // Fill the message
        messageBodyPart.setText(body);
        messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
         //Add the bodypart for the attachment(s)
        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart); //message is of type - MimeMessage
```

Comment: The entire method. It works for me. Check if I missed something in the snippet. Here's the entire [method](http://ideone.com/7ByeQs).

Comment: you're right. It worked for me too. I think the problem was in those two lines:                                                          MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
       messageBodyPart.attachFile(this.attachmentsDir.concat(file.trim())); So I had to do it your way. Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate into 2 parts to do this:

```
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // content part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(content);
        messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        BodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachmentPart.setFileName(file.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the only solution that worked for me. +1